# Is there a XSD-driven random XML test data generator?

Tags: c#, java, xml, delphi, xsd

For stress tests, I would like to create XML files based on a XSD with random (but valid!) test data. Is there a tool which can read a (simple) XSD file and build a XML file based on the schema definition?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Many tools exist to do this, check theses links

- [Microsoft XmlSampleGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx) (free), you can download the source code and build with  visual studio.
- [Liquid XML Sample Generator](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XML-Sample-Generator.aspx) (Great tool)
- [XMLSpy from Altova](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) (Expensive but complete)
- [XML Schema Editor from Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_schema_editor.html)
- [XML Schema Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716766.aspx),  included with visual studio
- [XML Generator from Stylus studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xml_generator.html)

Comment: I've used XML Spy to generate sample XML from an XSD file.  It's extremely easy!  http://bit.ly/9MGFZh  However I cannot advise if this is useful for generating many (hundreds) samples.  I've only used it for one or two samples.  Check out the free trial.

Comment: I've given them only a brief look, but it does *not* seem like any of them would use *random* data to generate the output. They all seem to use *sample* data only.